# What would the Native Code Debugger do for me in debugging an ASP.NET Web API project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-debugging, native-code, project-properties

In my ASP.NET Web API project's Properties page, Web section, it has several Debuggers that can be enabled at the bottom. Checked by default are ASP.NET and "Enable Edit and Continue." I see there is also a "Native Code" checkbox (as well as SQL Server and Silverlight, which are not "interesting" to me). How would my debugging experience improve or differ were I to check the "Native Code" checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know others how to debug web api application.

But for me, no special settings, just attach to the process(IIS or IISExpress, for real publish environment, we are demanded to local IIS debug).